# htaccess different user permissions for different users

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I can't seem to find the proper way to write my .htaccess file.  I initially had the file set up to allow access to a directory of files and that worked fine:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/technical/mep/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic

Require valid-user
```

Now what I need to do is add an additional htpasswd file (something like .htpasswd2) and allow those additional user to only be able to access a single file in that directory.  How do I edit my current .htaccess file to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `<FilesMatch>` container:

```
<FilesMatch protected.html>
  AuthUserFile /var/www/html/technical/mep/.htpasswd2
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null
  AuthName "Password Protected Area 2"
  AuthType Basic

  Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

And the file "**protected.html**" would use the `.htpasswd2` file.

Comment: So I could just add this in after my code above in the same .htaccess document?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1988799 Yeah, you can add this after what you have above. It will have precedence when the request is for the matched filename.